# Map property value not getting set correctly in Spring

Tags: spring

For my test **bean Map property is not being set properly and null value is getting set which i find on debug**.
Actually the bean has 3 properties and one of the property is a Map and rest are simple key value pairs.
The problem is that spring is setting 3 properties(from,html) correctly but is not setting the Map property ("to").
Below is the code and the solutions that i have tried. The "to" property of the `EmailInfo` class is getting set to null.

I have kept the constants in a property file and have used `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

I am sure there is no problem with the property file as the "from" property is getting set with the correct value.

```
<bean id="Info"
    class="com.src.framework.EmailInfo"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="to">
         <!-- <map>
            <entry key="DEV" value="${email.dev}" />
        </map> -->
        <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap">
            <entry key="DEV" value="${email.dev}"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="from" value="${email.sender}" />
    <property name="html" value="true" />
</bean>
```

The `EmailInfo` class

```
public class EmailInfo {

private boolean html;

private Map<String, String[]> to;

private String from;    

public boolean isHtml() {
    return this.html;
}
public void setHtml(boolean argHtml) {
    this.html = argHtml;
}
public Map<String, String[]> getTo() {
    return this.to;
}
public void setTo(Map<String, String[]> argTo) {
    this.to = argTo;
}
public String getFrom() {
    return this.from;
}
public void setFrom(String argFrom) {
    this.from = argFrom;
}
}
```

Please provide your suggestions are to what i am doing wrong here and how to rectify it.

Comment: Is `to` a `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: lutz "to" is a Map<String, String[]> in the code

Answer (score 0):

Try change signature of your map to `Map<String,String>` because it looks like you have not proper types in that map that you want to put it in xml.

But when you would like to have working your case with `Map<String,String[]>` you have change your xml

```
    <util:list id="myList">
         <value>foo</value>
         <value>bar</value>
   </util:list>
    <util:map>
        <entry key="DEV" value="myList"/>
    </util:map>
```

Comment: Thanks Rafik991. After trying out your suggestion i got the following error.Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'util:map'. No child element is expected at this point.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
Not allowed to change signature as its a code from a jar file

Comment: Try to redeclare your map and read my post again :) I made some changes.

Comment: Thanks Rafik991. But that did not work again getting the same exception. I cannot change the signature of the EmailInfo class as its given to me in a jar :(

Comment: Oh... so you have to try something more. Your exception is caused by XML validation. Check weather you have good namespaces in your xml

Comment: Try to review my listing I made some changes.